# R plotly: Stacked Area Chart with Cumulative Values not stacking properly

Tags: r, plotly

I've got three columns of data I would like to plot as a cumulative stacked area chart over a 10 day sampling period.

ID  variable    value

dallas  sample.01   0.0012

austin  sample.01   0.23

seattle sample.01   0.01

I'd like it to look something like this:

[image]

But it's coming out like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with my code?

```
melted_dat %>%
  group_by(value,ID) %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~variable, 
    y = ~value, 
    color = ~ID, 
    type='scatter', 
    mode = 'none', 
    fill = 'tonexty', 
    stackgroup = 'one',
    fillcolor = ~ID) %>%
    layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the groups trace by trace. As in the following example (from [here](https://plot.ly/r/filled-area-plots/)):

```
library(plotly)

data <- t(USPersonalExpenditure)
data <- data.frame("year"=rownames(data), data)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~year, y = ~Food.and.Tobacco, name = 'Food and Tobacco', type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', stackgroup = 'one', groupnorm = 'percent', fillcolor = '#F5FF8D') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Household.Operation, name = 'Household Operation', fillcolor = '#50CB86') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Medical.and.Health, name = 'Medical and Health', fillcolor = '#4C74C9') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Personal.Care, name = 'Personal Care', fillcolor = '#700961') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Private.Education, name = 'Private Education', fillcolor = '#312F44') %>%
  layout(title = 'United States Personal Expenditures by Categories',
         xaxis = list(title = "",
                      showgrid = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(title = "Proportion from the Total Expenditures",
                      showgrid = FALSE,
                      ticksuffix = '%'))

# Create a shareable link to your chart
# Set up API credentials: https://plot.ly/r/getting-started
chart_link = api_create(p, filename="area-stackedcum")
chart_link
```

Comment: That would be one solution, but I'd have to add hundred of traces! Could I make the plot without having to do that manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the cumulative example from plotly, don't do the `group_by .... cumsum`, I also get rid of `fillcolor`